# How to get label of field in error message from Netsuite Suitescript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am getting error messages from netsuite like

- `The field custevent97 contained more than the maximum number ( 5 ) of characters allowed`
- `You have entered an Invalid Field Value 1511 for the following field: contact`
- `Phone number should have seven digits or more.`

It is difficult to understand which field is wrong & which value is wrong.

How to get error message with label name of specific field from suitescript 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, all of the above errors will be returned by NetSuite when you try to save a record. So it won't be easy to overwrite them but you can use workaround as below.

Write your code in **try-catch** block and then validate error message to check if some field value is invalid. If field value is invalid, you can then fetch the said field from record using `nsRecord.getField`, and then fetch its label using **field.label**, and overwrite the error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do we know which field or value is invalid?

Comment: NetSuite does not gives you fieldId directly in error message, you will have to traverse the error.message to find fieldId that errorred.

Comment: yes, netsuite does not provide this granularity. you get a message and stack trace, which should be enough to debug